# SIMULINK - Variable Inertia/Mass Block creates

Tags: matlab, variables, block, simulink

Ran in to this problem when using Simulink today.
I'm trying to model a system with a variable Inertia.

But I keep getting 'Transient initialization' errors when trying to solve.
I located the problem, but can't find a solution:

This doesn't solve:

[image: Circuit with initialization errror]

Yet this circuit solves without any problem (the values are in the constant blocks are the same).

[image: Solves without problems]
Of course later on I want to feed a variable signal to the S-PS block!
Does anybody have an idea to resolve this?

Thanks!

For completeness a screenshot of the generated error:

[image]

Comment: I've seen this before, but I can't remember what the resolution was, or even if there was one. What release are you using? What are your solver settings?

Comment: Matlab R2016a, Solver is set to automatic (tried fixed step and variable), didn't help.....

Comment: Try using ode15s or ode23t solvers, they are much better and recommended for these types of problems (also check your max step size). You might also want to try adding a Gain block of 1 before the Simulink to PS converter block, or a PS Gain block of 1 after.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using a "PS Abs" Block! Connection as follows:

```
Constant->SimulinkPSConverter->PSAbs->VariableInertia
```